# Background-color in Bootstrap container not working in Electron

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, electron

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="container" style="border:1px black solid; width:500px;background-color:#cc5b1056;border-radius:3px;margin-top:190px;">

<div class="row">
<div class="col"><img alt="hello"  style="display:block;margin:auto;width:50%;height:auto;" /></div>
</div>


<div class="row">
<div class="col" style="text-align:center;padding-top:10px;"><input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" style="text-align:center;width:60%"/></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col" style="text-align:center;padding-top:20px;"><input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" style="text-align:center;width:60%"/></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col" style="text-align: center;padding:2%;padding-top:3%;">
<input class="btn btn-primary" id="submitbutton" disabled style="width:125px" type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

main.js

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

let mainWindow

function createWindow(){

    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width:1000,height:700})
    mainWindow.loadFile("Login.html")


}

app.on('ready',createWindow)
app.on('window-all-closed',function()
{
    app.quit();
})
```

This is what looks like opened in google chrome as an html file

[image]

This is what looks like open in Electron:

[image]

As you can see the background-color for container does not show up in electron. Anyone know why?

Comment: Is that not what I am doing?

Comment: You currently use `#rrggbbaa`which seems to be buggy. I was referring to forms like `rgb(0,0,255)`,`rgba(0,0,0,255)` or `#ff00ff`

Answer (score 0):

**May be this works:**

```
function createWindow(){

    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width:1000,height:700})
    mainWindow.loadFile("InstagramLogin.html")
    container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.style.backgroundColor = "#cc5b1056";
}  

<div id="container" class="container" style="border:1px black solid; width:500px;border-radius:3px;margin-top:190px;">
```

Comment: You cannot do that.

Comment: app.on('ready', function() {
    container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.style.backgroundColor = "#cc5b1056";
});

Comment: You think its a bug?